# Python IDE with integrated package management system

Tags: python, ide, package-managers

My friends usually ask me which Python IDE is easier to use, and I don't have an answer for them, because depending on their platform, package management could be a headache. Today I tried looking for a Python IDE with some kind of integrated package management system (e.g. PIP) that asks user if they like the IDE search online repositories for the missing package, and just install it--like the way their favorite TeX editor does.

So, do you know if such an IDE exists? If not, do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you deal with Django development, I think you should definitely check out [sourceLair](http://www.sourcelair.com) which offers integration with pip. You just right click on your requirements.txt file, select install dependencies and you're done.

Currently, you cannot search for pip packages but I suppose this could be a future feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think it mostly has to do with [python packaging hate](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/22/hate-hate-hate-everywhere/).  Binary package management is very important to Windows users (of which Python has many, because they don't treat Windows as a second class platform), and building many C extensions with distutils on Windows often just doesn't work (try 'pip install numpy' on Windows, for instance).  The state of "packaging" in python is confusing in general; I would say that's the primary reason nobody (that I know of) has gone thru the effort of integrating the existing tools into their IDEs.

As an aside, if you want something free and are familiar with eclipse, I recommend pydev.